# PHP Error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

I am a PHP newbe. I'm trying to load an array from this function:

funcs.php (sql returns 1 record)

```
function loaduser($conn, $mysql_db, $x_email, $x_password) {
$sql = "SELECT userid, userf, userl
        FROM ".$mysql_db.".users 
        WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $x_email)."' 
        AND pw = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $x_password)."'";
    //echo($sql);
    $Auser = $conn->query($sql);
    return $Auser;
}
```

loaduser.php

```
<?php require_once("../includes/funcs.php")

$x_email = $_GET['email'];
$x_password = $_GET['password'];
$Auser = loaduser($conn, $mysql_db, $x_email, $x_password);
var_dump($Auser);
if ($Auser[0]->num_rows > 0) {
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Auser);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $row["userid"];
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "0";
}
?>
```

but I get this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in loaduser.php on line 7

Please help me understand the issue TQ

EDIT - left $Auser[0] in by mistake should read $Auser->

EDIT - this worked fine when in same file and not in a function

EDIT - FIXED was db permissions issue - but no access denied error was shown

Comment: This is telling you that your query failed or returned no results. Add some error checking.

Comment: Your function will return only 0 or 1 because there is only query is executing not any array created.So $Auser has no index 0 or num_rows as well.

Comment: Augwa - the sql returns one row and have no failure when running query

Comment: Sunil - $Auser = $conn->query($sql) - this line creates the array?

Comment: Augwa - you were correct, the query was failing due to db permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$Auser` as a query result is not an array, so this should work:

```
if ($Auser->num_rows > 0) {
...
}
```

Comment: What is the output of the `var_dump($Auser);`?

Comment: output is boolean false

Comment: Well, then there was a failure during query. Check your query. The `echo($sql)` shows what?

Comment: SELECT userid, userf, userl FROM users WHERE email = 'x@x.com' AND pw = 'xxx'

have run in sql and returns 1 row

Comment: That seems unlikely, because according to your code, if `$mysql_db` is empty, then the table name would be `.users` (with period).

Comment: apologies removed db name from post

Comment: FIXED - was db permissions, don't understand why there was no "access denied" error